# How to execute Action asynchronously in .net 4

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have got this code in WPF application.

```
public void NotifyEntityUpdated(int userId, int entityId)
{
   Action currentAction = () =>
   {
      EntityUpdatedByUser(userId, entityId);
      SendEmail(userId, entityId);
   };
   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(currentAction);
}
```

How I can execute it asynchronously in .net 4?

As I see I cannot use async/await like this...

```
public async Task<T> DoSomethingAsync<T>(Func<T, Task> resultBody) where T : Result, new()
{
    T result = new T();
    await resultBody(result);
    return result;
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: Async using a thread? Use Task.Run( () => {} );

Comment: @Sievajet Would you mind to suggest entire answer, please?

Comment: Isn't using BeginInvoke already doing it asyc?

Comment: @BenCr: He's misunderstanding the word async.

Comment: You can install a [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) to enable `async/await` in .NET 4.0

Comment: Its asynchronous already. That what `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` is for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Using the .NET Task's you can do something like this.

1- First resolve and run the task

```
private Task ExecuteTask(Result result)
{
  return Task.Run(() =>
  {
     this.resultBody(result)
  });
}
```

2- Call it like this

```
await this.ExecuteTask(result);
```

// I dont have the VS here but I hope it will work ,good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the following:

1. The code I have got is correct and work asynchronously 100%.
2. The issue I am facing happening because second method SendEmail(userId, entityId); is taking time to be executed so the first method is firing later than it should.

So I found a working solution.

```
public void NotifyEntityUpdated(int userId, int entityId)
{
   Action currentAction = () =>
   {
      EntityUpdatedByUser(userId, entityId);
   };
   this.Dispatcher.Invoke(currentAction,  DispatcherPriority.Send);

  Action currentAction2 = () =>
   {
      SendEmail(userId, entityId);
   };
   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(currentAction2, DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
}
```

Comment: That's doesn't seem like a solution. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BenCr In my case it was a solution because I need to execute  `EntityUpdatedByUser(userId, entityId);` as fast as it possible in order to sync. Ribbon Windows.